# bash for loop quits with if statement

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, for-loop

This works:

```
for foo in `find . -name "*_aod"`
do
    bar=${foo}.gz
    if [ ! -e $bar ]
    then
        echo $bar
    else
        continue
    fi
done
```

This finds the first matching file and stops:

```
for foo in `find . -name "*_aod"`
do
    bar=${foo}.gz
    if [ -e $bar ]
    then
        echo $bar
    else
        continue
    fi
done
```

I would like someone to explain why this second code stops, and how I can write a one-liner that will proceed through the loop.

Comment: `find . -name '*_aod.gz'`

Comment: Do you have file names with spaces or other weird characters in them? If so, you might want to use `[ -e "$bar" ]`.

Comment: The second one does not stop for me.... Are you sure there's more then one `*_aod` for which a `*_aod.gz` exists? What happens if you use `[ -e "$bar" ]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should quote `$bar` where it is expanded. Otherwise, things like this can happen:

```
foo='a -a '; bar=${foo}.gz
touch "$bar"
[ -e $bar ] || echo "Whoa, '$bar' not there..."
ls
```

Output:

```
Whoa, 'a -a .gz' not there...
a -a .gz
```

(This example assumes the current working directory has been empty.)